# Inserting array element using foreach

Tags: php, sql, arrays, json, codeigniter

Hi i am working on a simple script where i would like to output the result of a given SQL query into JSON.

This is what i have so far:

```
$player = $this->game->getPlayer(5);
$leaderboard= $this->game->getLeaderboard(5);

$data = array(
            'player' => array(
                $player[0]->member_userunique, // USERNAME
                $player[0]->score, // HIGHSCORE
                $player[0]->memberid
            ),
            'leaderboard' => array(
                'score #1',
                'score #2',
                'score #3',
                'score #4',
                'score #5'
            )
        );
echo json_encode($data);
```

getPlayer(x) will return some information about the player. While getLeaderboard will get the top 5 records from the database. However, i would like to iterate each rows from the returned SQL result into the 'leaderboard' array.

I suppose i could use some brute-force by typing $leaderboard[0]->.... and so on but i would like to know the smarter way to do this.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: please show us the code how you fill $this->game ... or tell us how how we can know how many leaderboards there are. Also is the **5** in `getLeaderboard(5)` the number of items to return, or is it the identifier op the player ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like the below can be used to build up your array:

```
$leaderboardArray = array();
foreach($leaderboard as $num => $score){
    $leaderboardArray['score #'.$num] = $score; 
}
$data['leaderboard'] = $leaderboardArray;
```

Comment: thx for the hint, i took your solution and modify it a bit as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Just loop in your `$leaderboard` array and build your array to include later

```
$player = $this->game->getPlayer(5);
$leaderboard= $this->game->getLeaderboard(5);

$leaderboard_array = array('leaderboard'=>array());
foreach($leaderboard as $val)
{
    $leaderboard_array[] = 'score #' . $val;
}

$data = array(
        'player' => array(
            $player[0]->member_userunique, // USERNAME
            $player[0]->score, // HIGHSCORE
            $player[0]->memberid
        ),
        $leaderboard_array,
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could just let getLeaderboard return the array with the scores like you want it and then insert it into $data like this

```
$data['leaderboard'] = $leaderboard;
```

The second solution is looping the leaderboard array adding each element (Assuming the leaderboard is sorted in the order you want when returned from getLeaderboard)

```
foreach($leaderboard as $entry) {
    $data['leaderboard'][] = "Score #" . $entry;
}
```

This assumes the leaderboard returns an array of strings or numbers and that $data['leaderboard'] is empty when you do it. If it's not empty either unset it or use keys to reference the position you're updating

Comment: yup basically that's what i need. Thx for the help.